# Fetch posts from non blocking users

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm trying to fetch some posts from users that isn't blocking "me". Se models below:

```
User
  id
  username
  ....

Post
  id
  user_id
  content
  ...

Blockings
  blocker_id
  blocked_id
```

I need to fetch posts from **all** users that isn't blocking me.

I fetch all posts with:

```
@posts Post.all
```

But how do I joins this together.

Pseudo

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE "posts.user_id isn't blocking me"
```

I have a helper called `current_user` that returns the current logged in user "me".

Comment: If I understand your intent correctly, the SQL would be `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM blockings b WHERE b.blocked_id = $1 AND b.blocker_id = posts.user_id)` - where `$1` is the parameter `current_user`. Maybe that'll help formulate an ActiveRecord phrasing of the query; you can certainly test the SQL and make sure it does what you want.

Comment: It works like a charm. THX. But is it efficient enough? I have a couple of million records at the moment.

Comment: The best way to find out is `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do it with SQL would be:

```
select *
  from post
  where user_id not in 
    (select blocker_id 
    from blockings
    where blocked_id = 1);
```

Just replace the numerical id with the variable.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/900c2/2)

Comment: Ahh that is it! Sometimes the head isn't present! :) THX!

Comment: Watch out for `NULL`s in `NOT IN`. Make sure that `blocker_id` is `NOT NULL` or add a `WHERE blocker_id IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: @Craig One might argue that blocker_id should never be NULL in such a table. This should be enforced by a constraint.

Comment: @jt234 Exactly what I'm saying; if it *is not* declared as `NOT NULL` then you have to deal with `NOT IN`'s odd behaviour with `NULL`s. One never knows with Rails schema whether something will have appropriate constraints applied.

Answer (score 0):

In your Post class and a scope like this :

```
scope :not_blocked_from, lambda{|user| where("blocked_id <> ?", user.id)}
```

And you can fetch those posts you want as below:

```
Post.not_blocked_from(me)
```

Will work.

Comment: blocked_id is present in the Blocking model not the Post model.

Comment: oops, sorry, didn't read the question carefully. Still, you can add those join and condition stuff into the scope, make you flexable using it everywhere.